# How to Use Select and Group By and show part of result not all columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a problem that I want to solve it, but I don't know how, look at the query below here :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
p.pCode, 
p.pName, 
p.bPrice, 
od.oNumber,
od.pEach, 
SUM(od.qOrdered),
od.oLNumber


FROM products p INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON od.pCode = p.pCode 
GROUP BY p.pCode, p.pName, p.bPrice, od.pEach, od.oNumber, od.oLNumber
```

The result completely is OK, but I should not show `oNumber` and `oLNumber` in the result,(If I delete them in the select the result will be wrong) Is there any way to use `oNumber` and `oLNumber` in Group By without select them in the query?

Comment: From what you describe, it sounds like you would get rows in the result set  with duplicate keys.  That seems like it would be hard to interpret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement in SQL to *select* all columns which appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Rather, the reverse is true, namely all columns in `SELECT` must appear in `GROUP BY`.  Just remove the two columns from your `SELECT` clause:

```sql
SELECT
     p.pCode,
     p.pName,
     p.bPrice,
     od.pEach,
     SUM(od.qOrdered)
FROM products p
INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON od.pCode = p.pCode
GROUP BY
    p.pCode,
    p.pName,
    p.bPrice,
    od.pEach,
    od.oNumber,
    od.oLNumber
```

Note: Doing `SELECT DISTINCT` with your `GROUP BY` query is superfluous, because each group would already appear only once in the result set.

Comment: thank you @Tim you right it was my fault, I shouldn't use DISTINCT in this query, because that I get the wrong result